# How to create a result set of n*n in SQL (Oracle)?

Tags: sql, oracle, birt

i need to create a report (BIRT) with a matrix of n numbers that looks like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5
2 3 4 5 1
3 4 5 1 2
4 5 1 2 3 
5 1 2 3 4
```

For that reason, I need an ordered result set from my database that returns the cartesian product n*n, with the row number and the value beginning at the row number.

```
ROW  VALUE
 1     1
 1     2
 1     3
 1     4
 1     5     
 2     2
 2     3
 2     4
 2     5
 2     1
 3     3
 ...
```

I tried it by creating a cross join between the same number table two times,

```
select * from (
  (select level as nr from dual connect by level <= 5)
cross join 
  (select level as nr from dual connect by level <= 5)
);
```

but that yields only a result set with

```
ROW   VALUE
 1      1
 1      2
 ...
 2      1
 2      2
 ...
```

Any help appreciated, and sorry for the weird description of my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could generate numbers using connect by and use division and modulo to generate the row and value. The calculation in itself is quite simple, but you need a couple of `+1` and `-1`, because `level` starts at `1` instead of `0`

```
select
  trunc((level - 1) / N) + 1 as ROWNR,
  mod(level - 1 + trunc((level - 1) / N), N) + 1 as VALUE
from
  (select 5 /* Here goes your number N */ as N from dual) d
connect by
  level <= N*N
```

Comment: I changed the formula a couple of times, because I didn't notice the part of  value starting with row. Maybe it could be simplified a bit, but it seems to work nicely anyway.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you!